# iPhone Backup All Gallery Assets

Tags: ios, iphone, image-uploading, photosframework

My requirement is to fetch all the images from iPhone gallery, and run a background upload task of backing up those images to a server.(Like DropBox app). Has Anyone tried any algorithms for doing the same or could suggest a good strategy for doing the same. We can get all the images from the iPhone gallery using Photos Framework. Need to decide the rest of flow.

Comment: I think such background tasks lasts for only about 10 minutes or so. I am planning to resume it ones the app reopens

Comment: I worked on an upload feature and had massive problems with this. The problem is that in order to create a background upload task you need to have constant file access to the file you want to upload. With the Photo framework you only get a brief read access to the photo and need to store it somewhere else (creating a NSURLUploadTask with a photo url will actually crash). What I did was copying the files I need to the Documents directory and create upload tasks with fileURLs pointing to the Documents directory. After I finished uploading I deleted the copies. The problem is file size